# Strict mode violation Error happens when I try select an option which is a substring of another option

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

First off, I want to tell you that I am new to this playwright tool. My problem is, I have two option `male` and `female` when I try to click male option in the list using the following code,

```
page.getByRole(AriaRole.LISTITEM).filter(new Locator.FilterOptions().setHasText("Male")).click();
```

it throws the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Error {
  message='Error: strict mode violation: getByRole(AriaRole.LISTITEM).filter(new Locator.FilterOptions().setHasText("Male")) resolved to 2 elements:
    1) <li id="cP1Q100" class="z-comboitem">…</li> aka getByRole(AriaRole.LISTITEM).filter(new Locator.FilterOptions().setHasText("Female"))
    2) <li id="cP1Q200" class="z-comboitem z-comboitem-sele…>…</li> aka getByRole(AriaRole.LISTITEM).filter(new Locator.FilterOptions().setHasText("Male"))
```

This happens because male is the substring of female. If I try to click the female option it happens without having any problem because female is unique here. How can I resolve this problem? I am using Java Playwright.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76043828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wanna try to use RegEx. And Pattern in Java, I believe it's case sensitive by default, while text is not.

```java
page.getByRole(AriaRole.LISTITEM)
  .filter(new Locator.FilterOptions().setHasText(Pattern.compile("Male"))).click();
```

https://playwright.dev/java/docs/locators#filtering-locators

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same problem and it appears that playwright searches for substrings by default. To match text exactly, use the `exact` parameter as described [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-get-by-text).

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you use nth(index) method.

```
await page.locator('//button').nth(index).click();
```