# Playwright - Locator error :strict mode violation

Tags: typescript, playwright

I am getting the following error when I run test. I am fairly new to playwright and coding so I am not sure whats the solution

```
Error: locator.click: Error: strict mode violation: getByRole('button', { name: 'Statements' }) resolved to 2 elements:
1) <button title="Statements" aria-label="Statements" data-…>Statements</button> aka locator('#lp_line_6_a11y_queue').getByRole('button', { name: 'Statements' })
2) <button title="Statements" aria-label="Statements" data-…>Statements</button> aka locator('#lp_line_6').getByRole('button', { name: 'Statements' })
```

I just ran the test and was hoping to see to no error.

```
test('test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://www.test.com');    
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Section tag #1').click();
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Section tag #1').press('Control+a');
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Section tag #1').fill('inapptest');

  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'UPDATE' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Message us' }).click();
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Enter text here').click();
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Enter text here').fill('hi');

  await page.getByPlaceholder('Enter text here').press('Enter');  
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Statements' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Get statements' }).click();
});`
```

Comment: They give you the solution right in the message--you can pick one of those disambiguated locators.

Answer (score 8):

#### Locator Strictness

The Locator API is strict, meaning if it finds more than one element with your selector and you try to call a locator, like .click(), it will throw.

Look at the Strictness section here. I hope this helps.

https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#strictness
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator

You can explicitly opt-out from strictness check by telling Playwright which element to use when multiple elements match, through [locator.first()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-first), [locator.last()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-last), and [locator.nth()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-nth).

```
await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Statements' }).first().click();
```

Note: ***These methods are not recommended*** because when your page changes, Playwright may click on an element you did not intend. Instead, follow best practices to create a locator that uniquely identifies the target element.

#### Filtering Locators:

To make it unique, you may further [filter](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#filtering-locators) it by text:

Example:

```
await page
    .getByRole('listitem')
    .filter({ hasText: 'Product 2' })
    .getByRole('button', { name: 'Add to cart' })
.click();
```

##### Multiple Elements:

Of course you can find multiple elements if you need to  as well like table rows count.

```
await page.locator('tr').first().waitFor();
console.log(await page.locator('tr').count());
```

#### Or fetch complete table Data:

```
const table = await page.locator('.mytable')
const data = await table.evaluate((tableLocator) => {
    const rows = Array.from(tableLocator.querySelectorAll('tr'))
    return rows.map((row) => {
        const cells = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td'))
        return cells.map((cell) => cell.textContent.trim())
    });
});
console.log("data--> "+ data)
```

Reference : https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/10611

Comment: But how would one go about needing to get a list of rows for example and counting those?

Comment: Added an example for multiple elements as well.Hope it will help!

Comment: I hope it would help you guys!